# How do I manage multiple objects accessing an sqlite database in an iPhone app?

Tags: iphone, ios4, sqlite, fmdb

My iphone app has a single sqlite database that is accessed by many different model objects (FYI, I'm using FMDB). I'm using several helper methods to query the database and create objects from the results. I'm finding that most of the helper method code is being duplicated from model object to model object (eg: `MyObjectA` & `MyObjectB` both have these identical functions:

```
-(Foo *)getFooForKey:(NSInteger)key;
-(NSArray *)getBarsForFoo:(Foo *)foo;
-(Boo *)getBooForKey:(NSInteger)key;
```

`MyObjectA` & `MyObjectB` both have completely different purposes, but they rely on these helpers to get Foo, Bar, & Boo objects in order to serve their purposes.

What's the best way to make these helper methods available without duplicating a bunch of code? I don't want to use a singleton. Can someone provide some options?

Comment: Why not simply override the FMDatabase class?

Answer (score 0):

Simply override the FMDatabase or create a category if you like to extend features of your database wrapper.

However, you should not share the FMDatabase over several threads (Try to avoid sharing of the database wrapper). Simply create a FMDatabase Object for each object and you will be doing fine. Make sure, that you'll be using thread safe methods.

(The following lines are quoted from the FMDB documentation https://github.com/ccgus/fmdb)

> So don't instantiate a single FMDatabase object and use it across
>   multiple threads.
>
> Instead, use FMDatabaseQueue. It's your friend and it's here to help.
>   Here's how to use it:
>
> First, make your queue.

```
FMDatabaseQueue *queue = [FMDatabaseQueue databaseQueueWithPath:aPath]; 

[queue inDatabase:^(FMDatabase *db) {
    [db executeUpdate:@"INSERT INTO myTable VALUES (?)", [NSNumber numberWithInt:1]];
    [db executeUpdate:@"INSERT INTO myTable VALUES (?)", [NSNumber numberWithInt:2]];
    [db executeUpdate:@"INSERT INTO myTable VALUES (?)", [NSNumber numberWithInt:3]];

    FMResultSet *rs = [db executeQuery:@"select * from foo"];
    while ([rs next]) {
        …
    } }];
```